# Restrict MySQL user shutdown privilege

Tags: mysql

I have configured a user account that does not have any administrative roles, and only has access rights to a particular schema. However, I notice that this user account is still able to startup and shutdown the server.

How do I restrict this privilege for this user?

Comment: Are you sure that user doesn't have privilegies, what's the result of `select * from mysql.user where User='mysql-user'`?

Comment: result is "...command denied to user ..."

Comment: Try to execute it with `root` user. You're looking for `Shutdown_priv` column, where value should be `N`. By the way, did you flush the privilegies in order to tell the server to reload grant tables?

Answer (score 0):

in order to check what privileges he has, use `SHOW GRANTS FOR <username>;`
you should check that he doesn't have, SHUTDOWN, RELOAD or ALL privileges.

If he does, remove it using `REVOKE <privilege> ON *.* FROM '<username>'@'localhost';`

of course this should be executed as root (or a user with GRANT privilege)